# jQuery - Elements fade in/out on page scroll

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a page whereby, when you scroll down, an image fades out. Then, as you scroll down a little more, a new image fades in as it enters the page.

I have very small knowledge of jQuery, and so I did a search for solutions to this problem on this website. I found a piece of code and added it to the site, but it had zero effect on the website. Is this because images are being used.

Here is the code:

```
var subsectionTop = $('.sub-section').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
if ((subsectionTop - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
    $('.sub-section').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
} else {
    $('.sub-section').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
}
});
```

I am very stuck and would appreciate any help you guys could offer me. Thanks :)

P.S. here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RK9d/4/) with all of my code

Comment: your fiddle is missing jquery (you can add it in the left sidebar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made some changes to your code and added jquery to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RK9d/7/)

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
         var subsectionTop = $('.sub-section').offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var y = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (subsectionTop < y) {
                $('.sub-section').fadeTo(100, 0);
            } else {
                $('.sub-section').fadeTo('slow', 1);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works very well in the fiddle, but when I implement it into the website nothing happens. Do you know why this is? Thanks

Comment: i'm assuming you did the same mistake you did in fiddle, you didn't include your JQUERY. add this in your `<head>` tags `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Still no luck. I copied and pasted all of my code into another fiddle just to test and it worked fine, but there is still no result when the code is on my actual project file. I added that script as you suggested, but it's still not working.

Comment: did you add the code above into your <head> tag under `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` ?

Comment: updated my code above and added `$( document ).ready(function() { });`

Comment: `<html><head> JAVA SCRIPT CODE HERE</head><body></body></html>`

Comment: Awesome! It works now. Thanks so much. I'll accept your answer now, but one more question: how would I achieve the same effect for the next image (fades in when enters screen, fades out when exits)?

Comment: you want them to both fade at the same time?

Comment: No, I need the user to scroll down, then the second image appears. Is that possible?